# Enable/ disable a button in Client when an event on server is finished

Tags: c#, .net, angular

I am developing a .Net core project with Angular on Frontend and c# on backend. I am new to web development and i am looking for ideas or little help on achieving a task.

I am connecting my Angular frontend to an External server using .net web server. I am able to post data to External server successfully using Http services. After i receive response from external server the results are queued in my controller. Before i send response to client i want to enable a download button on Client, only if i receive response from the External server and the results are queued in my controller successfully. If there is no response from External server I do not want to enable download button.

Appcomponent.html

```
 <button mat-button id="getdoc" (click) = "getdoc()" [disabled] = "disabled" >Download</button>
```

Appcomponent.ts

```
  getdoc() {
    this.download.downloadDoc()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.datadownload = new Blob([res], { type: 'application/txt' });
      //  { this.disabled = false };
         saveAs(this.datadownload);
        console.log(this.datadownload);
      }, error => {
        console.log('error while downloading', error)
      })
}
```

Appservice.ts

```
export class DownloadService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  downloadDoc(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('URL', {/* headers, */ reportProgress: true, responseType : "blob"});
  }
}
```

Controller

```
namespace ang.Controllers
{

    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DoController : Controller
    {
 private void OnProvideData(DataAndHeader dat)
        {

            CommHeader header = (CommHeader)dat.Header;

            switch (header.Type)
            {
                case  CommHelpers.CommType.ServerToClientReceived:                    
                    break;
                case CommHelpers.CommType.ServerToClientFinished:


                    string ClientID = header.ClientID;
                    ConcurrentQueue<DataAndHeader> queueResultsForClient = null;
                    if (!dicResults.TryGetValue(ClientID, out queueResultsForClient))
                    {
                        queueResultsForClient = new ConcurrentQueue<DataAndHeader>();
                        if (!dicResults.TryAdd(ClientID, queueResultsForClient))
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    queueResultsForClient.Enqueue(dat);
                    break;
            }               
        }

 [HttpGet]
      // [Route("download")]
      public byte[]  download(string ClientID)
      {

           // some logic
            return new byte[0];

      }
}
}
```

I want to wait till i get the Response from the External Server and loaded into my Controller after that i want to enable the button. After the button is enabled and clicked by Client he should be able to download file.

The "getdoc()" works only when i click download button. but initially the download button is in disable state. I want to programatically enable it from my controller not from my Client

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code:

```js
  getdoc() {
    this.download.downloadDoc()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.datadownload = new Blob([res], { type: 'application/txt' });
         saveAs(this.datadownload);
         console.log(this.datadownload);
         this.disabled = false; // This is the change
      }, error => {
        this.disabled = true;
        console.log('error while downloading', error)
      })
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your time. I have already implemented that successfully. I am also able to download file. I implement this logic in a post request so when the request is finished the button was enabled. My question is how can i trigger the getdoc() function directly from the webserver to enable the button. I think i have to implement some logic in OnProvidedata method in My controller. but do not know how.

Comment: are you talking about calling an angular method from your c# code? its impractical and unnecessary. Can you please explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @AnandBhushan, Thanks for your reply. I want to enable the download button on my Client. This download button has to be enabled only after i receive data from external server to web server. When i click the download button then the getdoc() function has to be triggered. In OnProvidedata function in my controller i recieve the response from the External server. when the data is ready the download button  should be triggered automatically.

Comment: @user821 , what I see from the code is that you are calling `getdoc` method on click of the `download` button. Now again calling the `getdoc` method is not good.

Comment: @user821, and moreover u cannot directly trigger a typescript method from a server.

Comment: @ngShravil.py The "getdoc()" works only when i click download button. but initially the download button is in disable state. I want to programatically enable it from my controller not from my Client.

Comment: @ngShravil.py Are there any ways to notify my client when the response on webserver is ready.

Comment: @user821 , you cannot notify or something like that, but if you want to execute some code after, the service call is successful, you can write the code after `this.disabled = false;`